# Trouble using pyenv and anaconda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyenv

I'm using pyenv to manage my python environments. One of the environments is anaconda with multiple environments.
There are two ways to activate a conda environment while everything is handled by pyenv.

1. Load the conda environment directly with pyenv as `pyenv local anaconda3-2019.10/env/myenv`
2. Load the main conda and then activate the local environment `pyenv local anaconda3-2019.10; conda activate myenv`

Both methods fail one way or another:

In the first method, `conda` command cannot be used to install any more modules as it says `command not found`

In the second method, the `conda activate` fails, complaining about the shell: `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.` Configuring the shell ruins all the environments by changing .zshrc which is global

I can use `pip` to install packages but the whole point of using anaconda is to use the nice package managing environment

Have I set something wrong or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: I am using Pyenv and Anaconda together, but not by installing Anaconda's Python with Pyenv. Is that what you're doing? I've installed Miniconda entirely separately from Pyenv and have Conda disabled by default (there's a config option to not activate the base environment while putting the Conda function into your shell). When I want to use a Conda environment, I just `conda activate envname` and everything works fine. Only problem is I can't use `pyenv local` but I use `pyenv-virtualenv` to be able to have many environments

Comment: @darthbith yeah I've used pyenv to install Anaconda. The hope was to prevent Anaconda from changing anything system-wide that I'm not aware of. Some of the other packages I use have dependencies I don't want to break unintentionally. Anaconda is in `pyenv install --list` so I assumed it should know how to handle it.

Comment: Anaconda is pretty well self-contained. If there are no environments activated, nothing (except the `conda` function itself) will be accessible unless you've changed something manually. But if you use the built-in conda machinery, then nothing should be changed.

Comment: @darthbith that's one way to go with it. Sometimes conda can have lots of bloatware and the packages I wanted were not on the latest version ( I think one example was plotly). SO conda was giving me a headache. Decided to have pyenv so I could have a clean version of python with only a few working packages.

Comment: What do you mean bloatware? You can install Miniconda, which includes only Python and conda in the base environment. Then you have complete control over what packages get installed.

Comment: @darthbith Means, I've made a mistake and am too far in now to back out so naturally, I blame anaconda. I like the convenience of anaconda for the data science projects, but sometimes conda just installs older versions than pip. I guess I can just pip install in anaconda but I'd rather keep them separate.

Comment: @anishtain4 Conda should not mess with much system-wide, unless there really is no way around it, that would somewhat defeat the point. If you want to keep your packages as up-to-date as possible and cut down on the bloat, then you should use Miniconda with the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) channel, not Anaconda.